# How to get counts of two different column's from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the counts from two tables and both the tables having different columns names.

Example:-table A has column account_manager and table B has column assigned_to

TableA

```
account_manager   
----------------+--------------
Ishan Sharma | 
Mahak Kagra | 
Vibha Bhatt | 
Himanshi Jain | 
Sucheta | 
Simran | 
Bhawani | 
Bhawani |
Alfiya Zumana | 


TableB

assigned_to   | 
-------------------+--------------
Simran    | 
Himanshi Jain    | 
Bhawani    | 
Vibha Bhatt    | 
Vibha Bhatt    |
Vibha Bhatt    |
Alfiya Zumana   |
Alfiya Zumana   |
Alfiya Zumana   |
```

Output

```
            Name   | count
-------------------+--------------
Alfiya Zumana      | 4
Bhawani            | 3
Himanshi Jain      | 2
Ishan Sharma       | 1
Mahak Kagra        | 1
Simran             | 2
Sucheta            | 1
Vibha Bhatt        | 4
```

The query which i have try

```html
SELECT distinct account_manager as RM,COUNT(account_manager)  AS RM1 
FROM tableA 
union all 
select distinct assigned_to as RM, COUNT(assigned_to)  AS RM1 
from tableB 
where status = 'Site Visit Done' 
GROUP BY RM
```

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`, since grouping makes it distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` should happen in each individual table. Since you need the count of both tables together, you need to restructure your query such that the group by happens after `UNION ALL` which merges the data for the 2 tables.

```
SELECT name, count(name) as cnt FROM 
(
    SELECT account_manager as name FROM TableA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT assigned_to as name FROM TableB
) T1
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Hi Ash thanks for your help. The query which you provide is working fine also thanks for description it really help me to understand query.